# Receive hash from Perl Script to use in PHP

Tags: php, perl

I have a perl script that does a lot of config file parsing for me and creates a hash with all the information I need.

I want to call that script from PHP and have PHP get the hash to be able to work with the hash in php and not just returning some html code from the perl script.

Is that possible? Haven't found any way yet and just know that I am able to return lots of html code as output, but that's not what I want the perl script to do.

Comment: Do you know WHY it is returning the HTML? Is it because the Perl script is programmed that way? Normally I would use bash to run it and get it's output but it sounds like it's out IS HTML.

Comment: no, maybe this was written a bit crazy.. I know how to have the perl script produce html as output and have that output catched by php. But what I want is to have the hashmap. I have written that perl script.

Comment: JSON.  Perl can easily produce it.  PHP ought to easily be able to parse it.  Done.

Comment: Don't complain about others answers if your question is *that* vague

Comment: Can you show us what this output is? As answers say it is normally better to output as a JSON string and then parse that info PHP

Comment: @DavidO Though the OP makes it clear he has no problem running the script it is parsing it's output. I read that uber clearly.

Comment: It's a great idea to encode it as json and I will use that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way, serialize this hash into `json` in perl and print resulting string to STDOUT.

In PHP it can be easily decoded into array or object...

Comment: it's not yet outputting json but I can make it output json :-)

Comment: From CPAN: JSON, possibly with JSON::XS back-end.  Not sure what PHP tool is good for parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

If the platform that is executing the PHP allows for it, you can call the exec() function to execute external files like:

```
$result = exec( "/path_to/your_script.pl", $lines, $state);
```

Comment: I was reacting to your text: "I want to call that script from PHP... Is that possible?".

Comment: I know, but imho I made it pretty clear that it's not about calling the script or receiving textoutput ("[..]and have PHP get the hash to be able to work with the hash in php and not just returning some html code") Never mind and was not intended personally.

Comment: Unnecessary all the same. PS, if you want to keep your Perl as is for backwards compatibility, you may also consider using PHP DOM to parse the output.